# 特定のディレクトリの中身を、そのディレクトリから相対で tar を作るには？

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

`tar` コマンドで特定のディレクトリに対して `.tar.gz` の中身を解凍する時には、次のように実行します。

```
$ tar xvzf hoge.tar.gz -C ./hoge/
```

この逆の操作を今実行しようとして、次のように実行しようとしたらエラーになりました。

```
$ tar cvzf hoge.tar.gz -C ./hoge/
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

特定のディレクトリの中身に対して、そのディレクトリの中から相対パスで、 tar.gz を作成する方法などありますか？

Comment: `-C` は処理を行う前に指定したディレクトリに移動(`change directory`)するので、`tar cvzf hoge.tar.gz -C ./hoge/ .` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-C` は処理を行う前に指定したディレクトリに移動(change directory)するので、

```
tar cvzf hoge.tar.gz -C ./hoge/ .
```

とすれば良かったです。